# How to use the eval statement with a list of strings?

Tags: python-3.x, eval

How can I use the `eval` statement with a list of strings?
Example: a list `["math.sin", "math.cos", "lambda x: x * 2", "lambda x: x ** 2"]` and a value `x = 1`.
My task is to return a list with results of the expressions.

Comment: Are the items in the list of the type `string`?

Comment: Yes @KshitijSaraogi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import math

exprs = ["math.sin", "math.cos", "lambda x: x * 2", "lambda x: x ** 2"]
x = 1

functs = map(eval, exprs)
# or: functs = (eval(e) for e in exprs)

results = [f(x) for f in functs]
```

Comment: Thanks[answer] @Amadan